# SystemJS, Angular2: switching between min/dev bundle

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs

I want to use `Angular2` along with `SystemJS`, in such way so I can easily switch between production and development. In development I prefer to use class per file, rather than in production I'd like to use single minimized `angular2` bundle.

Currently I have the following `index.html` and `config.js`:

**indexl.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('ts/main.ts').catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

**config.js:**

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',

    typescriptOptions: {
        emitDecoratorMetadata: true
    },

    map: {
        'angular2': '/node_modules/angular2',
        'rxjs': '/node_modules/rxjs'
    },

    paths: {
        'typescript': 'node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js',
        'http': 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js'
    },

    packages: {
        angular2: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    }
});
```

**Question:**

The above code works good for development. Please suggest, how to change `System.config` in order to use `angular2` from a single `/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js`. Adding `angular2.min.js` to `<script ...></script>` is not an option, because in this case I will not be able to switch between `dev` and `min` bundles dynamically (assume that `index.html` is a static page)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is nothing to configure in SystemJs if you want to use `/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js` since modules are explicitly registered into this file using `System.register`.

So you can remove `angular2` from the `map` block of your SystemJS configuration.

Comment: But how will it (`/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js`) be loaded? Currently there is no reference to it in `System.config` and I don't want to load it explicitly via HTML's `<script>` section - because in this case it will be loaded in development too

Answer (score 0):

In development, you can use their UMD bundle, here is the systemjs config file from official guide

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

In production, you can use the same setting, but this time you use SystemJS Bundler or Webpack. 
Also you must not use `*.min.js` anymore since it doesn't support tree-shaking optimization like [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup)

For setup example, [refer](https://github.com/antonybudianto/angular2-starter) here